# Why was the question “Why does the IRS require US taxpayers to report dividend income per country” closed as opinion-based?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

Why was the question “[Why does the IRS require US taxpayers to report dividend income per country](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/140863/5656)” closed as opinion-based?

The existing answer demonstrates that there exists a very much objective answer to the question.

Comment: Agreed. Voted to reopen. Needs 1 more vote as of this comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question has been reopened, so the issue is fixed. Still no idea why it got closed though!